# Can someone add my question useful tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging

A few minutes ago I wrote a question called [What was the fifth card of the dead man's hand?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/922/what-was-the-fifth-card-of-the-dead-mans-hand)

But because of my reputation, I couldn't add any useful tag for this question. Can someone do that?

Comment: What tags would you think are useful?

Comment: Could be `poker-history`, `dead-mans-hand` tags useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now my reputation is more than 150, I can create new tag and adde to my question [poker-history](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poker-history) and [dead-mans-hand](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dead-mans-hand) tags.